# PHP date function accept null or empty string and return value

Tags: php, date

it's amzing when i send a null value in date() as a second parameter then it returns some time? how to remove this thing. i want that if a string is null or empty then doesn't do anything

```
    $x=strtotime();
    var_dump($x);
    var_dump($x==NULL);
    echo date('H:i',$x);
```

display

```
 Warning: strtotime() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given in 
 D:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 1
 bool(false) bool(true) 05:30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes perfect sense. NULL equals `0` in this case. `date()` counts from 0, which was January 1st, 1970, 0:00:00 UTC.

You are based in Jaipur. Your timezone is [**UTC + 5:30 hours**](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=44). Thus, `date(0)` on your server, in your time zone, will result in January 1st, 1970, 5:30.

Answer (score 1):

Why not check the value of `$x`?

```
if($x != NULL)
    echo date('H:i',$x);
```

Comment: I M USING date() in mysql query, how can i do this inside mysql query

Comment: Do your check before executing the query?

Comment: no, actually i m inserting like `insert into tbl_x(rank,open_time) in values('1',date('H:i',$x)),('2',date('H:i',$y)),('3',date('H:i',$z));` where open_time is time type field in mysql and $y and $z have some value

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter to the `date()` function is optional: if it's not provided, `date()` uses the current time. If you want to prevent this you have to check your variable before calling it, or write a wrapper function and use that instead of `date()`.